# How to parse nested JSON object arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, typescript

We're writing an Extension for WeClapp (https://www.weclapp.com/api2/). Custom Attributes in WeClapp could be added to almost all Datatypes. These Attributes are accessible over a nested JSON object Array.

Interface example:

```
export interface ICustomAttribute {
    attributeDefinitionId: string;
    booleanValue?: boolean;
    dateValue?: number;
    entityId?: string;
    numberValue?: number;
    selectedValueId?: string;
    stringValue?: string;
}

export interface IContact {
    id: string;
    ...
    customAttributes: ICustomAttribute[];
    email: string;
    ...
}
```

Response Example:

```
{
  "id": "4317",
  ...
  "customAttributes": [
    {
      "attributeDefinitionId": "4576",
      "booleanValue": null,
      "dateValue": null,
      "entityId": null,
      "numberValue": null,
      "selectedValueId": null,
      "selectedValues": null,
      "stringValue": "Test"
    },
    {
      "attributeDefinitionId": "69324",
      "booleanValue": true,
      "dateValue": null,
      "entityId": null,
      "numberValue": null,
      "selectedValueId": null,
      "selectedValues": null,
      "stringValue": null
    }
  ],
  ...
  "email": "name@domain.com",
  ...
}
```

There is no Problem accessing the IContact (contact in the following example) properties expect the `[customAttributes]` property. How can I access and manipulate Data?

In the following example `contact = IContact`:

```
console.log(contact);
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {
    id: '102570',
    ...
    customAttributes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    ...
  }
]
```

```
console.log(contact.id); //Outputs: 102570
console.log(contact.customAttributes); //Outputs: undefined
```

JavaScript Array Extensions (`length`, `ForEach`, ...) are not available on `[contact.customAttributes]`, because it's `undefined`:

```
let attributes = new Array(0);
attributes = attributes.concat(record.customAttributes);

console.log(attributes); // Outputs: [undefined]
```

I also tried to Change the interface and tried to reparse:

```
export interface IContact {
    id: string;
    ...
    customAttributes: string;
    email: string;
    ...
} 

...

let attributes Array<ICustomAttribute>  = JSON.Parse(record.customAttributes);
```

I have no idea why I can't Access the Array. The strangest thing is that setting attributes does not throw any errors:

```
let attribute: ICustomAttribute = { attributeDefinitionId: "4576", stringValue: "Test" };
let contact = { customAttributes: [attribute] };
```

This new entry could be posted and Returns as shown above.

Output of `JSON.stringify(contact)`:

```
[{"id":"102871",...,"customAttributes":[{"attributeDefinitionId":"4229"},{"attributeDefinitionId":"46381"},{"attributeDefinitionId":"69316"},{"attributeDefinitionId":"98781","stringValue":"77b5d0f1-b1a4-4957-8ea2-ea95969e3c03"}],...,"email":"name@domain.com"}]
```

Output of `console.log(contact["customAttributes"])` is `undefined`.

Comment: How do you get the data from the API? Could you possibly have an unfulfilled promise in there somewhere?

Comment: i'm runnig a restify server.  one endpoints preloads the data in a module in a persistent memory array (Array<IContact>). the other endpoints loops throught this Array (.forEach). i don't use promises in any part of the the project. only npm packages are restify and request (not the promise ones).

Comment: Try using JSON.stringify to log the IContact so you can see exactly what you're getting.

Comment: @matt helliwell Added: Output of JSON.stringify(contact):

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(contact['customAttributes']);`

Comment: result => undefined

Answer (score 0):

If your `console.log(contact)` yields:

```
[
  {
    id: '102570',
    ...
    customAttributes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    ...
  }
]
```

Then this suggests that `contact.customAttributes` does not exist. `contact` is an array of objects, and to reach the first, you would need `contact[0].customAttributes`

Comment: thx, for reply. i can Access the other properties (see: console.log(contact.id); //Outputs: 102570). so the contact object is not an Collection. am i wrong?