# Accessing JSON objects nested inside array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nested

I've been trying to access the JSON from [this API](https://api.collegefootballdata.com/rankings?year=2019&week=1&seasonType=postseason). However, when I run a request to retrieve the JSON I'm met with the following list when I run this code.

```html
const request = require('request');

var url = 'https://api.collegefootballdata.com/rankings?year=2019&week=10&seasonType=regular'
request(url,(err, res, body) => {
    if(!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(obj);
    }
});
```

My output:

```html
[
  {
    season: 2019,
    seasonType: 'regular',
    week: 10,
    polls: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

My problem here lies in the fact that I want the information from each POLL (5 polls listed as objects in the JSON by following the link, however I cannot figure out how to WORK with this.) For example, I would want to call polls[0].rank to populate a list of the top 25 teams from the poll.

Accessing the arrays of objects inside nested JSON has obviously been a problem for me in Node, and would love to get started on the right foot when working with this project.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: So how would I go about accessing those tagged as Objects in that array I listed? @Andreas

Comment: Not an answer but the same Problem. [how-to-parse-nested-json-object-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025775/how-to-parse-nested-json-object-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JSON, there are 3 separate polls, and each poll has it's own top 25 list in `ranks`.

```
obj.polls[0].ranks
obj.polls[1].ranks
obj.polls[2].ranks
```

`ranks` is array of objects as well, so if you want to see the school the reference would be

```
obj.polls[0].ranks[0].school
```

You can easily examine the JSON, in a browser, using developer tools and Network tab.

[image]

Comment: When trying to call that example (console.log(obj.polls[0].ranks.school) I'm still getting        " console.log(obj.polls[0].ranks[0].school);
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Try `obj[0]` -- just need to get the root of the problem (pun intended)

Comment: Getting somewhere! The polls are no longer showing as 'Objects' in my array. => {
  season: 2019,
  seasonType: 'regular',
  week: 10,
  polls: [
    { poll: 'Coaches Poll', ranks: [Array] },
    { poll: 'AP Top 25', ranks: [Array] },
    { poll: 'FCS Coaches Poll', ranks: [Array] }
  ]
}

When doing obj[0].polls[0] it loads! I guess I just wasn't aware I had to first index the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

since `polls` is an `array`, I would love to use `map` 
so my code could be

`obj.polls.map((pol)=>{
 // so you can access the object pol which includes ranks and other proprites 
 // do whatever you want here 
}`